# How to replace matched pattern in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a Perl program that accepts an input pattern and print the string with the matched part enclosed with parentheses. For example, if I input the regex ".p" and the string is "developing", it should print "devel(op)ing"

Here is my program:

```
if (/($pattern)/) {
    $_ =~ s/$1/($1)/;
    print;
} else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

When I run it, I got the error message:

> Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at q1.pl
>   line 12, <> line 1.

The string "devel()ing" was returned.
I did some research and seems like the $1 is uninitialized because the string is not matched, but in my case, the $1 should always be initialized since I checked with "if...else..."

Comment: FYI, instead of doing a match and then a substitution, you could do omit the match and do the substitution in the conditional.  The return value of `s///` is the number of substitutions made which in your case will be either 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the match, `$1` contains the string `op`.

The substitution than matches the `op`, but there are no parentheses in the search part, so `$1` gets cleared, and there's nothing to substitute the `op` with.

Add the parentheses to create the capture group again:

```
s/($1)/($1)/;
```

Answer (score 3):

`$1` in a replacement contains the first capture group in the match, but there are no capture groups in your regular expression. You can use `$&` to get everything matched by the regular expression.

```
s/$1/($&)/;
```